# Custom Config section in App.config C#

Tags: c#, configuration, custom-configuration

I'm a quite beginner with config sections in c#
I want to create a custom section in config file. What I've tried after googling is as the follows
Config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="MyCustomSections">
      <section name="CustomSection" type="CustomSectionTest.CustomSection,CustomSection"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <MyCustomSections>
    <CustomSection key="Default"/>
  </MyCustomSections>
</configuration>
```

CustomSection.cs

```
    namespace CustomSectionTest
{
    public class CustomSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("key", DefaultValue="Default", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 60)]
        public String Key
        {
            get { return this["key"].ToString(); }
            set { this["key"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this code to retrieve Section I get an error saying configuration error.

```
var cf = (CustomSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CustomSection");
```

What am I missing?
Thanks.
**Edit**

What I need ultimately is

```
    <CustomConfigSettings>
    <Setting id="1">
        <add key="Name" value="N"/>
        <add key="Type" value="D"/>
    </Setting>
    <Setting id="2">
        <add key="Name" value="O"/>
        <add key="Type" value="E"/>
    </Setting>
    <Setting id="3">
        <add key="Name" value="P"/>
        <add key="Type" value="F"/>
    </Setting>
</CustomConfigSettings>
```

Comment: Please review the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935331/how-to-implement-a-configurationsection-with-a-configurationelementcollection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983127/custom-configurationsection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="customAppSettingsGroup">
      <section name="customAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <customAppSettingsGroup>
    <customAppSettings>
      <add key="KeyOne" value="ValueOne"/>
      <add key="KeyTwo" value="ValueTwo"/>
    </customAppSettings>
  </customAppSettingsGroup>
</configuration>
```

**Usage:**

```
NameValueCollection settings =  
   ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettingsGroup/customAppSettings")
   as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;

if (settings != null)
{
 foreach (string key in settings.AllKeys)
 {
  Response.Write(key + ": " + settings[key] + "<br />");
 }
}
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to get this to work quickly.  3 things   :  1. YOU MUST ADD a Reference to System.Configuration in your references,  2. using System.Configuration;  3. using System.Collections.Specialized;

Comment: You can also omit the group (customAppSettingsGroup) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
var cf = (CustomSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyCustomSections/CustomSection");
```

You need both the name of the section group and the custom section.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this didn't work for me somehow. please look at edited part of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Highlight ConfigurationSection press F1,
You will see that the implementation on the MSDN website overrides a property called "Properties" which returns a "ConfigurationPropertyCollection", as your properties have a matching attribute of that type you should be able to populate this collection with your properties if not wrap them in the same way the MS guys have.